# Performance tuning on join two tables columns with patindex

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Sample data:

Note:

1. The table `tbl_test1` is filtered table, may have less records based on filtered earlier.
2. The following is just the data sample for understanding purpose. The actual table `tbl_test2` is having 70 columns and 100 millions of records.
3. The `WHERE` condition is dynamic comes with any combination.
4. The display columns are also dynamic, i mean one or more columns.

   ```
   create table tbl_test1
   (
     col1 varchar(100)
   );
   insert into tbl_test1  values('John Mak'),('Omont Boy'),('Will Smith'),('Mak John');

   create table tbl_test2
   (
    col1 varchar(100)
   );  
   insert into tbl_test2  values('John Mak'),('Smith Will'),('Jack Don');
   ```

query 1: The following query is take more than 10 min and still running for 100 millions records.

```
select t2.col1
from tbl_test2 t2
inner join tbl_test1 t2 on patindex('%'+t1.col1+'%',t2.col1) > 0
```

query 2: This also keeps running unable to get the result after 10 min of wait.

```
select t2.col1
from tbl_test2 t2
where exists 
( 
    select * from tbl_test1 t1 where charindex(t1.col1,t2.col1) > 0
)
```

expected result:

```
 col1
 ----------
 John Mak
 Smith Will
```

Comment: A clause like `patindex('%'+t1.col1+'%',t2.col1)` isn't SARGable, so the only way the DBMS can find out if the clause is true is by scanning **every** row in the table and checking the values; for a table with 100M rows (possibly with very long values in the columns `t1.col1` or `t2.col1`) that is a big ask. Have you considered full-text indexing?

Comment: @Larnu, My bad, Forgot to mention that table `tbl_test1` is the filtered table which is having less records compare with table `tbl_test2`.

Comment: @Larnu, Do I need to create full-text index on both table in my case?

Comment: But `tbl_test2` has 100M rows. it needs to scan both sides of the "coin".

Comment: I've honestly never worked with Full-text indexes; i know the usage cases for them and the benefits, but I have no need for them in the environments I've worked, so I'm afraid I'm ill-prepared to give advice based on experience.

Comment: I appreciate that a requirement is a requirement, but its worth checking whether this needs to be a pattern matching comparison and not just equals.  If you could use t2 LIKE('%' + t1.Col1) i.e match strings with start with the search pattern that MIGHT be quicker if you can out an index on t2.

Comment: https://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/01/20/optimizing-substring-search-performance-in-sql-server/ may be of help.  It talks about index seek being used if LIKE pattern + '%' is used.